# What is wrong with codeigniter mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to fetch records from my database with check in date, check out date and contact id but I am unable to get success please help me to solve, I am using Codeigniter.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('events');
$this->db->where('contact_id',$contact_id);
$this->db->where('check_in_date >=',$chkIn);
$this->db->where('check_out_date <',$chkout);
$data = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM (`events`) WHERE `contact_id` = 4 AND `check_in_date` >= '2014-09-14' AND `check_out_date` < '2014-09-25'
```

Comment: Show us more code. And I'm assuming you are using `$this->db->get();` after your code.

Comment: yes I am using $this->get....

Comment: You could add `print_r($this->db->last_query());` after `$data = $this->db->get()->result_array();`. And maybe run that query in phpMyAdmin to see the results.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the printed mysql query there.

Comment: ok done please check question now

Comment: Do you have any records that fit the query?

Comment: yes i have checked in database record are there according to query

Comment: Then the error is probably somewhere else, not in this part of the code.

Comment: Would you please print your query which is returning CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use DATE('value') or DATETIME('value') whatever suits you.
Also make sure formats are matching.

```
$this->db->where('DATE(column) <= ', 'DATE('.$value.')');
```